# Number format evaluate to integer or fraction

Tags: excel, vba

I want to output this pipe size in Excel without formatting the size.
[image: API from 3D software]

- My Excel VBA code cannot read the `"` (inch) sign thus deleting the data after the sign i.e. `[1];1;2`
- `service`, `line nr.` and `from/to` data does not show
- I tried formatting the size from the API raw data to output it without the " (inch) sign. Unfortunately it gives me the integer value which is correct but the fraction "3/4" results to "44624".

How do I make these values from "SIZE" copy as is without formatting?

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        
    Call FormatCells
    Call GetDataFromCSVFile
    Call separateData
    Call CreateHeader
        
End Sub
    
Sub GetDataFromCSVFile()
    '
    ' Creates connection to extracted file
    ' Export to new file
    '
    
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim defaultDirectory As String
    Dim SQLString As String
    
    defaultDirectory = Dir(ThisWorkbook.path & "\extractfiles\*.csv")
    
    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
    
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    cn.ConnectionString = _
    "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
    "Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.path & "\extractfiles\;" & _
    "Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"
    
    cn.Open
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Source = "SELECT * FROM [DATA-FLOWCODE.csv]"
    rs.Open
        
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    
    'Move to 2nd row to create header rows on A1
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
End Sub

'***
Sub FormatCells()
    '
    ' test1 Macro
    ' format cells
    '
    
    Cells.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
    'Format this columns as fractions
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("C7", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            .Select
            .NumberFormat = "# ?/?"
        End With
    End With
        
End Sub
'***
```

Which formatting should I use or not, to have the raw data format as is?

Comment: Would be helpful to have a sample of the csv file you're reading from.

Comment: how do I attach the csv file in here?

Comment: You can copy/paste some of the content into your post, or put a link to a file on google docs or any other host

Comment: Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11JBcuOQyu3RNPDCKjShsbFcB4mhvtlNA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There's no "inch" symbol in your data sample?

Comment: No, I have removed it from my 3D API to output without the sign. for the reason that when the excel macro runs and exports the unopened csv file some datas are missing after the inch sign. It looks like excel treat the inch sign as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can do it without ADO - it's a bit more work but you get more control/flexibility over how the data gets read/displayed.

```vb
Sub ListDataFromCSVFile()
    
    Dim lines As Collection, cDest As Range, data, arr, i As Long
    Dim col As Long
    
    Set lines = GetLines(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\data-FLOWCODE.csv")
    If lines.Count < 8 Then Exit Sub 'only header lines present...
    
    Set cDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    For i = 8 To lines.Count        'starting after header lines...
        data = LineData(lines(i))
        For col = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
            With cDest.Offset(0, col)
                .NumberFormat = "@"  'set format *before* value...
                .Value = data(col)
            End With
        Next col
        Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1)   'next row
    Next i
End Sub

'read all lines from a text file into a Collection
Function GetLines(f As String) As Collection
    Dim coln As New Collection
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile(f, 1)
        Do While Not .atendofstream
            coln.Add .readline
        Loop
    End With
    Set GetLines = coln
End Function

'extract data from a line as an array of values
Function LineData(ByVal line As String) As String()
    Const SEP As String = ";"
    Dim arr, tmp
    arr = Split(line, "<STRING>")
    If UBound(arr) = 1 Then 'should be only one <string> per line
        tmp = Trim(arr(1))  'get the second part after <string>
        tmp = Right(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1) 'trim off leading/ending '
        tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)
        LineData = Split(Trim(tmp), SEP) 'return as array of values
    End If
End Function
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: See error https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wMc7H_CvB3EKuUTyXJzpevVZPwX6BFmK?usp=share_link. In my original code I have tried formatting it the same way you have did before copying the data inside the macro, unfotunately excel finds it as a fraction 3/4 and then automatically do the calculation or set it as a date. I dont know how excel would copy fractions and treat it as a text without doing any formatting or dividing it.

Comment: try this: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wMc7H_CvB3EKuUTyXJzpevVZPwX6BFmK?usp=sharing

Comment: Using the file `DATA-FLOWCODE.txt` as the source, this works fine for me. See example output above.  I can't really follow what's going on in your screenshots.

Comment: You are correct when the file is in .txt format, excel does not formats the fraction. While if I change to .csv format it changes to a date or gives another value as shown on error 1. Another thing is that when I continue running the code it gives me an error 2 from this line "For col = LBound(data) To UBound(data)"

Comment: In your "csv" format you removed the "<STRING>" part of the line, so that's going to break the code in `LineData`.  Why not just read the txt file, since that's the format of your original output?

Comment: I'm trying to extract the data to csv because it automatically separates the data from delimited symbol ";". And since it is an excel ext. file I was hoping to come up with an output with a single file wherein I was hoping if I would be able to make a code like a vbscript to format the data automatically and give me just a single file. Instead of output to a txt file and another macro file would run to read and do something with the txt file.